# An unnatural martingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

What is an example of a real valued stochastic process $X$, and a filtration $\mathcal F_t$ such that $X$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal F_t$ but not it’s natural filtration?

Either continuous or discrete time examples are fine.

Comment: If $\mathcal{G}_t$ is the natural filtration, then $\mathcal{G}_t\subset\mathcal{F}_t$ because for all $s\leq t$, $X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s\subset\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. So you would have $E(X_t|\mathcal{G}_s)=E(E(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)|\mathcal{G_s})=E(X_s|\mathcal{G_s})=X_s$.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I couldnt come up with anything. I missed this, thanks!